# How can I check if an SSL configuration for an HTTPS connection is valid?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I'm trying to write a utility class (as I haven't been able to find one), that allows me the check that an HTTPS connection is okay. When I curl the site I get the error

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
```

When I access the site on Chrome, I get

```
The identity of this website has not been verified. Server's certificate does not match the URL. The server could not prove that is is *.domain.com; its security certificate is from *.another.com.
```

This is exactly what I'd like to test for in Java but I haven't been able to do so. How can I test that the SSL connection is okay?

Comment: you might get using `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`

Comment: Caveat: curl and Java in general use (partly) different TLS configurations (especially independant truststores). So you might still get different results from Java and curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way could be to to do a GET to a given URL. If the connection is OK must return an HTTP 200 OK response code, else the Java request library e.g Java's `HttpsUrlConnection`, Apache's `HttpCLient`, Ning's `HttpClient` should return the exception.

It is very rudimentary but depends on your needs could serve.